# How can goat milk be prepared to reduce the 'hairy' after taste it has?

Tags: flavor, milk, mixing, goat

I have bought goat milk as an alternative to cow milk. Others and myself say that there is a strong 'hairy' after taste which makes it less pleasant. Adding sugar does not dilute/reduce that taste. Is there any way of preparing it or adding something to it to make this after taste softer?

Comment: I don't know about after it's been produced, but for people raising the goats, it's been shown that having females penned w/ the males changes the flavor.  Also storing the milk for long periods (which happens w/ stuff in stores) and/or not keeping it cold (a byproduct of pasteurization?) are known to increase the 'goatiness' of the milk.

Answer (score 3):

I think I understand what you mean about "hairy" taste; I think of it as a "goaty" taste. Unfortunately, the diet of the goat contributes much more to the flavor of the milk, than sheep or cow diets/milk. This is one of the reasons that goat milk is a favorite when it comes to cheese making. It adds a little funkiness to the cheese.

Now all that said, how are you drinking your milk? I love goat yogurt and cheese, but I'm not crazy about goat milk in my coffee. Part of this has to do with the temperature at which your consuming the milk. I usually eat my yogurt cold, and the goatiness is noticeable, but not as much as when I try to drink it in my coffee. Warm/hot foods tend to "taste" stronger, while cold foods kind of numb your taste buds.

I know that I haven't answered your question. I think if you drank it for a while (say two weeks), you'd notice it less and less. Kind of like moving from whole milk to skim milk.

Comment: For lamb, people put cardamom, there must be a herb or preparation method to help

Answer (score 0):

Without having tasted it myself, I am told that goat milk just be served icy cold, otherwise it tastes off in a musky, goaty or hairy way as you put it.